# Failed to start production mysql server. No log messages either

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, amazon-ec2

This is a production instance (EC2) we are managing for a client. Downtime already 5 hours. I am screwed.

**The Story**

This morning I found one of our clients mysqld process in killed state. I did `sudo service mysql start` and got it up and running.

The log informed that this was happening due to table crash. After going through some references on the internet, I executed the following commands:

```
# mysqld was running
$ mysqlrepair -A --auto-repair
$ mysqlrepair -A -o
# By the time the following command was executed, mysqld had stopped
$ mysqlrepair -A -c
```

Ever since, the following commands refuse to start mysqld

```
$ sudo service mysql start
start: Job failed to start

$ sudo mysqld --verbose
$ ps aux | grep mysql
ubuntu   24124  0.0  0.1   8108   936 pts/0    S+   04:07   0:00 grep --color=auto mysql

$ sudo mysqld_safe
131130 04:09:02 mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mysql/error.log'.
131130 04:09:02 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
131130 04:09:02 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
```

There is nothing of the current timestamp in /var/log/mysql/error.log.

```
$ dmesg | grep mysql
[776212.640137] init: mysql main process (24070) terminated with status 1
[776212.640189] init: mysql main process ended, respawning
[776213.629832] init: mysql post-start process (24071) terminated with status 1
[776213.650730] type=1400 audit(1385784344.772:92): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/sbin/mysqld" pid=24094 comm="apparmor_parser"
[776213.745904] init: mysql main process (24098) terminated with status 1
[776213.745957] init: mysql respawning too fast, stopped
```

The configuration file is: http://pastebin.com/hbvLGqEM

Comment: This isn't a question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by adding to my.cnf:

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 16M
```

Reference Mike's answer:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/127264/cant-start-mysql-mysql-respawning-too-fast-stopped